# Which plugins/gems should I use to dynamically generate thumbnails on-the-fly in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, the thing is. I'm building my first rails app which reads images from a directory and it's subdirs. Now, I want to generate dynamic thumbnails of those images. But I don't want to fill up that directory with the thumbnail images. I was thinking of caching these thumbs separately for each user in temporary directory.

Oh, and, I would also need the dimensions of the images for some css magic.

What plugins/gems/... should I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `rmagick` coupled with `Paperclip`. In this way you can specify the dimensions (and many other attributes of the images), and make thumbnails on the fly.

On top of this, I would also add in `delayed_job` which will background the process of the images so if any of them are provided by the client, they won't have to wait for it to complete client-side.

rMagick : http://github.com/rmagick/rmagick

Paperclip: http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

delayed_job: http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: +1. `delayed_job` is not necessarily part of the equation, but still very useful. Here's the obligated tutorial if you wanna learn more http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip